# Reading "null"s from binary file C#

Tags: c#, file, binary, arrays, filestream

I wrote a small function that reads binary file to a byte array.
But there is 1 bin file that when I'm reading it, it gives me "null"s (if its char[]) or zeros (if its byte[]), I see it when I'm in debug mode.
The thing is that when I'm using in the same function to read another bin file it works fantastic!

Here is one piece of code:

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        BinaryReader r = new BinaryReader(fs);
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        {
            data[i] = r.ReadByte();
        }
```

Here is another function that I'm using:

```
        byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (byte b in fileBytes)
        {
            sb.Append(Convert.ToString(b, 2).PadLeft(8, '0'));
        }

        File.WriteAllText(outputFilename, sb.ToString());
```

clarification - the binary file that I'm trying to read is NOT empty and contains some strings (seen this when I'm opening it with some file editing tools).

Also, these Pisces of codes reads successfully other binary files.

What can be the problem?
There are differences between one binary file to another?

Comment: When you say "null"s or 0's (zeros), can you be more specific? If the data array is byte[] you should only be seeing zeros if there are zeros in the file. How could you be seeing nulls?

Comment: @BobDalgleish I getting zeros if its byte[] and nulls if its char[]. I edited my original question.

Comment: Again, is the content of the file compatible with the bytes you read in? Have you looked at the content of the file and made sure that the actual bytes are zero or not zero? If you get different results with different files, no one is surprised.

Comment: Before I go too much farther, is this C# or Java? You need to tag your question so you get the best possible help.